# Query through VB fails (Infopath and Access)

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, infopath2010, infopath-2007

I am working on an infopath form using MS Access as the database.

On the form, I want to check emails for duplicates and I am trying to do this by running an SQL query from within the following VB code.

```
    Public Sub CTRL125_7_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ClickedEventArgs)

    Dim myAdoConnection As AdoQueryConnection = _
    DirectCast(Me.DataConnections("Mainconnection"), AdoQueryConnection)


    Dim mynav As XPathNavigator = _
    CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:Candidate_Tracking_Database/@Email", NamespaceManager)

    Dim email As String

    email = mynav.InnerXml

    myAdoConnection.Command = _
    "select [Email] from [Candidate_Tracking_Database] where [Email] =" + email

    myAdoConnection.Execute()
    End Sub
```

I want to continue this with an If, then, else statement to prompt if the duplicate is found. However, I get the following error when I try to execute the code:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
Message="The query method on the Document object failed.
Operation aborted"
```

**What am I doing wrong?** Thanks in anticipation of an answer.

**Notes:**

I have Adapted the code from - 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.adoqueryconnection.command.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Elements in the Code are:

```
Mainconnection = connection name
"/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:Candidate_Tracking_Database/@Email" = Xpath of the input text box
[Email] = Field name in the [Candidate_Tracking_Database] table
```

Complete Error is:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
Message="The query method on the Document object failed.
Operation aborted
"
Source="Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Client.Internal.Host"
StackTrace:
   at      Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.MomExceptionHelper.ExecuteDataConnectionAction(OMCall d)
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.AdoQueryConnectionHost.Execute()
   at Candidate_Registration.FormCode.CTRL125_7_Clicked(Object sender, ClickedEventArgs e) in C:\Infopath\InfoPath Projects\Candidate Registration\FormCode.vb:line 300
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.ButtonEventHost.OnButtonClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust._ButtonEventSink_SinkHelper.OnClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`myAdoConnection.Command = _
    "select [Email] from [Candidate_Tracking_Database] where [Email] =" & email`

or this:

`myAdoConnection.Command = _
    "select [Email] from [Candidate_Tracking_Database] where [Email] ='" & email & "'"`

Comment: The second line of code worked. However, there is another error. Will check it in the evening and get back to you guys!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Everything is super fine!! ... Thank you!!